# Simple .desktop shortcut available for Ctrl+Super+D to show/hide desktop/minimize windows?

Tags: shortcut-keys, .desktop

Ctrl+Super+D to show desktop/minimize windows can't be used due to QNAP VM browser client on Windows because this shortcut creates a new Windows desktop on host instead.

Because I'd like to keep my installation on a minimum level I don't want to install bulky 3rd party tools.

Is there a simlple .desktop shortcut available which I can put on the dock or desktop to show/hide desktop?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: latest Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS